# Redmine test mail failed to connect to gmail

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, redmine

Can any one please help to solve sending emails via gmail.

> An error occurred while sending mail (Connection refused - connect(2))

Here is the issue details

http://www.redmine.org/issues/10123

Please spare your precious time for this issue.
Thank you

Comment: As there is a lot of information on the Redmine forum about sending mail via gmail it would be useful if you could explain what you have tried and what the specific problem is- rather than just linking to another problem report.

Answer (score 0):

As you appear to be trying to send the mail via gmail then I believe you will need to install the tls plugin `action_mailer_optional_tls_plugin`

Have you followed the instructions on the Redmine blog?

http://www.redmineblog.com/articles/setup-redmine-to-send-email-using-gmail/

Comment: Sir @Adrian, Thank you for reply. you wont believe but I have gone through all the steps mentioned there. Another thing the plugin link mentioned there is not working. I tried it. One more thing I read that action_maier is required for Ruby version 1.8.6 and I m using 1.8.7

Comment: In which case you need to break down the problem so you can work out which parts are working and which aren't. For example can you send emails via a different mail account that doesn't need tls? Can you try the sendmail option? etc

Comment: Sir @Adrian, as u said I have already tested it using Hotmail, gmail, but not working the same error-Connection refused. The final step, i will have to go through actual code, can u tell me how can i make email failure detailed log entries into production.log file?

Comment: @RajanRawal You can do the following to show detailed error logs.  

1. Open `/config/environments/production.rb` for editing  
2. Comment out the line `config.action_mailer.logger = nil`  
3. Change the this line `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`